# How to "pull" a user into a room when another user clicks their name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am building a socket chat and right now I'm trying to add a function that enables users to click on another online user from a list, and thereby start a conversation (room), which is private/invisible for other users. 
It should essentially work the same way as Facebook's chat function, where you can click on a friend and start texting.

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how that would work, since the 'clicked on' user does not voluntary joins the conversation.

Below you can see my code. I hope someone can point out any errors I've made or something I am missing.

**Update**, messages are now being received by the 'clicked on' user's end, however messages are not going the other way.

**Step 1**, client-side: A user clicks on a name of an online user

```
//Starting conversation
$("#people").on('click', '.list-group-item', function () {
    var peopleName = $(this).children("span").text();
    var peopleID = $(this).children("span").attr("class");
    //this har INTET id! Hvordan tilføjer jeg det til update-people, når user logger ind?
    socket.emit("serverCreateConversation", peopleName, peopleID);
    $("#msg").prop("readonly", false);
    $("#msg").attr("placeholder", "Your message");
    $("#send").attr("disabled", false);
    $("#chat").empty();
});
```

**Step 2**, server-side: The conversation gets created, and pulls the 'clicked on' user into the conversation.

```js
// Creating conversation
 client.on("serverCreateConversation", function(conversationReceiver, id) {
  console.log("About to create conversation with:", conversationReceiver, id);
  var key = uuid.v4();
  conversationStarter = people[client.id].name;
  var conversation = new Conversation(conversationReceiver, key, conversationStarter);
  conversations[key] = conversation;
  sizeConversations = _.size(conversations);
  client.emit("update-conversations", {conversations: conversations, count: sizeConversations});
  client.to(id).emit("update-conversationsForReceiver", {conversations: conversations, count: sizeConversations});
  client.conversation = conversation.key;
  client.join(client.conversation);
  //conversation.addPerson(client.id);
  conversation.addPerson(id);
  people[client.id].conversation = key;
  //chatHistoryInConversation[client.conversation] = [];
  console.log("Created conversation", conversation.people);
  client.to(id).emit("pullReceiverIntoConversation", conversation); //Pull conversationReceiver into conversation
  client.emit("addConversationForSelf", conversationReceiver);
  client.to(id).emit("addConversationForOthers", conversationStarter);
 });
```

**Step 3**, client-side: The 'clicked on' user' receives the conversation from the server and contacts server again.

```
//Pulling conversationReceiver into conversation
socket.on("pullReceiverIntoConversation", function (conversation) {
    socket.emit("assigningConversationKeyToReceiver", conversation);
});
```

**Step 4**, server-side: The conversation key gets assigned to the 'clicked on' user.

```js
//Assigning conversation key to receiver
 client.on("assigningConversationKeyToReceiver", function(conversation){
  people[client.id].conversation = conversation.key;
  client.join(client.conversation);
  console.log("Pulled", people);
 });
```